# Can I access the interface of a COM object from different threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, com

I get access to the [IAudioEndpointVolume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370892%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface in the main worker thread of a service like this (error checks omitted):

```
CoInitialize(NULL);
CoCreateGuid(&g_guidMyContext);
CoCreateInstance(CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator, (void**)&m_pEnumerator);

IMMDevice *pEndpoint = NULL;
m_pEnumerator->GetDevice(&deviceID[0], &pEndpoint);

IAudioEndpointVolume *pAudioVol = NULL;
pEndpoint->Activate(__uuidof(IAudioEndpointVolume), CLSCTX_ALL, NULL, (void**)&pAudioVol);

CAudioEndpointVolumeCallback *pVolumeCallback = new CAudioEndpointVolumeCallback(pAudioVol, 100, TRUE, m_debugLog, m_logMutex);
```

The `CAudioEndpointVolumeCallback` class then stores the `IAudioEndpointVolume` pointer in a member variable and calls `RegisterControlChangeNotify(this)` on it in its constructor.

This class may also start a thread to smoothly change the volume from one value to another over a short time period. So at the end I make calls to the `IAudioEndpointVolume` interface from different threads. In general all of this works as intended, but I am experiencing some strange behavior in some edge cases. When checking the code again I stumbled across the comments about threading in the MSDN documentation (I don't have any prior experience with COM objects) and wondered if what I am doing is correct.

So, is it safe to make calls to the `IAudioEndpointVolume` interface from different threads with the code above? Do I have to protect those calls with a mutex?

I am a bit confused and am not sure if I really understood the [behavior of the COM Threading Models](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809971.aspx).

Comment: Very unlikely that this has anything to do with threading, given that you make the calls from the same thread that obtained the interface pointer.  Very likely that this has a lot to do with using a service.  You should have quoted your [previous question about this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21490109/volume-changes-without-creating-notification-for-iaudioendpointvolume).

Comment: I don't make (all) the calls from the same thread that obtained the pointer! I made a few changes to my code regarding thread safety and this solved some other problems I had with this service. So this pointed me in the direction that lead to me posting this question. I will try your suggestion from the other question at a later time. Actually I doubt that it will solve the problem as posted in the comments over there. I will try it anyway. However, please don't take this personally ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CoInitialize(NULL)` initializes single threaded apartment (STA) and interface pointers you have there are only [supposed to be] valid on this thread only. You can pass them to another thread through [GIT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678517%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or by [`CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693316%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on this thread and getting a "duplicate" of it back with [`CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691421%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the target thread, where you are going to use it.

Depending on implementation behind the interface pointer in question you might eventually obtain the same pointer (in which case the whole trick would be equal to simply using the pointer on another thread), however this is not safe in general case.

Another option is to use MTA (as opposed to STA) and then you are allowed to pass pointers directly among all/any MTA threads.

Comment: So if I use `CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED)` and protect the access to the interface with a mutex, I am safe? But I have to call `CoInitializeEx` in both/all threads?

Comment: Yes you are safe. Yes, on all threads. Note however that you often don't have flexibility to choose STA/MTA. If the thread is already initializes as STA by the caller, you don't have an option to re-initialize. In most cases the problem is stated like this: "My code runs on STA (MTA) thread, how do I correctly use pointers on worker threads".

Comment: @RomanR. I have a similar situation with IUIAutomation interface. I create it in a MTA  thread, but then the pointer is passed around and used by other threads. Those threads have not called coinitialize and make calls on the interface without synchronization. Everything seems to work fine, but is it safe? How is possible that other threads can use the interface in this way? Thanks

Comment: @lorenzolightsgdwarf The safe use of the pointers is to pass within apartment (that is to pass to another thread if you know it's MTA or you initialize it as MTA yourself). If you don't do this, it might still work out because of so called "implicit MTA" - if you have at least one MTA thread then other threads having no COM initialization will be considered by COM as implicitly initilialzed as MTA. Sometimes also the speceific COM server implementation is such that calling on wrong apartment has no consequences and so you can see things working for this reason as well.

Comment: @RomanR. you have been very clear, thanks. One more obscure point to me: if I call a function on the pointer from two threads (let's say I call IUIAutomation::ElementFromPoint), , assuming MTA initialization on both, do I need to synchronize them with a mutex?

Comment: COM servers (and APIs and their objects of sorts) designed to work in MTA are typically assumed for consumption from multiple threads and so they are responsible to be prepared for concurrent calls and add synchronization on their end. So you normally can safely call COM object from multiple threads in MTA. There might be some specific reasons or you know upfront the API is buggy or have special needs, in this case you would want to try some synchronization outside.